# Python: Concise way of updating a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Often when I'm working with dictionaries whose values are lists, I happen to code this:

```
if k in D:
    D[k].append(x)
else:
    D[k] = [x]
```

Is there a more concise way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
D = defaultdict(list)
D[k].append(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most concise way is to use [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) like:

```
D.setdefault(k, []).append(x)
```